# DocuSign for Salesforce - Removing Add Recipients button on Envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I am sending documents from Salesforce for Signature using DocuSign using Custom Button on the Custom Object record. I am capturing the recipients in the record and passing the details in CRL, CCRM, CCTM. Now i want to remove the feature to Add or delete or Edit the recipients that are showing in the Envelope just before send. Could any one subject what i could do to achieve this.

Thanks in-advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the documentation (http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSign_for_Salesforce_Administrator_Guide.pdf), I don't think it's possible to show the Envelope confirmation/review screen to the sender and NOT allow them to modify Recipients.  The closest you could come would be to set `OCO='Send'` -- but that would result in the Envelope being sent immediately when the button is clicked (i.e., wouldn't display the Envelope confirmation/review screen at all) -- so your button code would need to supply all required Envelope information, and the sender wouldn't have the opportunity to review/change any of the information prior to the Envelope being sent.